# Unable to Join Farm

Tags: 2013

I've been trying to join a new server to the farm. I've installed SharePoint 2013 onto the machine and configured it. I've ran all the updates. My first mistake was not allowing mixed authentication on SQL, so it couldn't communicate, but now that that's been changed to mix, I've run across another problem: **Unable to connect to the remote server.**

I've:

- Pinged the servers on the farm I want to connect to. They are found.
- Verifying all permissions. I am using farm admin to try this.
- Ran the configuration wizard, and chose the option to join the farm. I have the password, but I can't join for the above error. This error comes on the page before I can enter the password.

One thing I'm not certain about it I've run all Windows Updates on this new server, and the older server may not have the newer updates. Would this be a problem?

Comment: If you plan to install on a 2012R2 there is no problem for windows update, done this about 2 days ago.
All your servers are domain-joined ?

Comment: Yes, they are joined to the domain! I don't believe it's 2012 R2, though, but rather just 2012 Servers. Would that also be an issue?

Comment: I don't think so. I installed on 2012 servers too about 2 weeks ago, without any problem. Hum, what about firewall ? did you disable it on domain ?

Comment: Did you try a simple reboot (after patchs/hotfixes) ? Other thing, farm admin got good rights on SQL ? (securityadmin/dbcreator on the sql instance)

Comment: I believe so. I don't have a lot of access, so I can't say with certainty. Would this be an action I perform on the server itself? I have also enabled the port for SQL, in case that additional information makes a difference.....

Comment: Yup! I have tried restarts. I may try to tear down the server and rebuild it just case that would make a difference. I'm sure I've forgotten something important.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16192/discussion-between-catherine-lam-and-nico).

Comment: What are your installation type, standalone or complete?